# popToRootViewController does not work with an array of UINavigationControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with an array of UINavigationControllers (like the iPod app) so I can switch tabs and each tab have a stack of view controllers within it.

I want to be able to pop all view controllers back to the root if the users touches a new tab so have implemented the UITabBarController delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 // Pop all view controllers back to the root view controller
 for (UINavigationController *nc in tabBarController.viewControllers){
  [nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 } 
}
```

To check this is working properly I have put a break point on the dealloc method of my various viewControllers.

It seems the tab I am switching to pops to the root view controller, but the tab I am switching from doesn't.  I am missing something obvious here?  I have 4 tabs and the for loop gets executed 4 times, and makes 4 separate calls to popToRootViewController.

The reason this is important is if I am at the rootViewController it is safe for me to update the underlying database without leaving the user in a view that no longer makes sense or is valid.  For example, the root has a table of items, touching an item gives you detail about that item.  If the user touches another tab the detail item view controller is still in memory.  If the app receives an update where this record is no longer valid then tabbing back to it will cause a crash or inconsistent state.

Hope that makes sense and any help would be useful even if it is simply ideas on how to troubleshoot the problem.

Regards

Dave

P.S.

This all stems from the fact that my app used to check for an update at startup throw out the old database and use the new one.  With iOS4 and above my app doesn't get killed anymore so have to check for the update in applicationWillEnterForeground as well, the major difference being the app is not in a known state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a work around, although I am not sure why it works, so happy to accept a more fuller explanation.

I have also implemented the other UITabBarController method shouldSelectViewController

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    // Pop all view controllers back to the root view controller
    for (UINavigationController *nc in tabBarController.viewControllers){
        [nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This works PROVIDED the animated flag is set to YES.